# When using dataframes the columns attribute is not shown

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using pandas version 0.25.3

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.workbook import workbook

df_csv = pd.read_csv('Names.csv',header=None)
df_csv.columns # I don't get the columns option and throws traceback when I try to force.
```

Does anyone know reason why this would be true - why some dataframe attributes would be missing?

Comment: What do you mean that you "don't get the columns option"? One thing I notice is that you set `header=None` when reading in the csv. That means you've instructed pandas to not look for column names in the csv and pandas will give you default numbered column names of 1,2,3,etc. If your csv has header names in the first row, then you need to set `header=0` instead.

Comment: Can you censor values in Names.csv and then show us what df_csv is outputting? It's possible that your csv isn't being read into the dataframe as you'd expect, but we can't know why unless we can see what's in Names.csv.

Comment: AFAIK, a DataFrame **requires** Index objects along both axes. I can't imagine why that's not the case. Perhaps try to create a [mcve] using StringIO to reproduce the problem. Only you have acces to `'Names.csv'`.

Comment: We don't have any data to reproduce this, and even if we did I would be quite surprised if we could. The only thing I can think of is that you might be using a Pandas version which is older than the one in which `.columns` was introduced, although I'm not sure what version that would be.